# React trying to make a sidebar with redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm new to react, trying to make a sidebar.

I've succeeded to reach to the reducer so far.

```
// sidebarReducer.js
const sidebar = (state = { visible: false }, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case "SHOW":
        console.log("show"); 
        return { ...state, visible: true };
    case "HIDE":
        console.log("hide");
        return { ...state, visible: false };
 default:
    return state;
  }
};

export default sidebar;
```

.

```
class SidebarContainer extends Component {
handleOpen = () => {
    this.props.dispatch({ type: 'SHOW'});
}
handleClose = () => {
    this.props.dispatch({ type: 'HIDE'});
}

handleToggle = () => {
    const { visible } = this.props;
    const { handleClose, handleOpen } = this;
    if(visible) return handleClose();
    handleOpen();

    console.log(visible); // ouput : undefined.
}

render(){
    const { visible } = this.props;
    const { handleToggle, handleClose } = this;

    return[
        visible && <Dimmer onClick={handleClose} key="dimmer"/>,
        <Sidebar visible={visible} onClose={handleClose} key={0}/>,
        <Hamburger active={visible} onToggle={handleToggle} key={1}/>
    ]
  }
}

export default connect()(SidebarContainer);
```

When the handleToggle event is invoked, I get two logs which are "show" from console.log("show") of the sidebarReducer.js and "undefined" from console.log(visible) of the SidebarContainer.js.

when the visible is true, dimmer, sidebar, hamburger component will be shown.
but since I don't know the reason why the visible is undefined, It's not showing. Can you please tell me the reason??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `render` you are importing `visible` from `this.props`:

```
const { visible } = this.props;
```

But how are they passing to the component props?

The `visible` value is storing in the Redux and should be connected to React component, so then you can use it.

As you can see there is nothing connected:

```
export default connect()(SidebarContainer);
```

So you need to connect it like that:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    visible: state.REDUCER_NAME.visible // propably sidebar
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(SidebarContainer);
```

Please check [Implementing Components](https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact#implementing-components) section in Redux Doc. for deeper understanding.

**NOTE:** the same thing about actions (functions which are you calling from props: `this.prop.actionName` - they also should be connected to the component, through `mapDispatchToProps`)

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect your component to your state / actions.

```
export default connect(state => ({
    visible: state.sidebar.visible
 }),
 {
   show: sidebarActions.show
 }
 )(SidebarContainer);
```

something like that.

Check : mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps methods from redux documentation